# Getting Picker.Item key for onValueChange React Native

Tags: react-native

I have this code below:

```
<Picker
  prompt="Select Province"
  selectedValue={province}
  onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
    setProvince(itemValue);
    handleProvinceChange();
  }}
  style={styles.form}
>
  <Picker.Item label="Select Province..." value="select" />
  {dProvinces.map((provinceObj) => {
    return (
      <Picker.Item
        key={provinceObj.ProvinceID}
        label={provinceObj.Province}
        value={provinceObj.Province}
      />
    );
  })}
</Picker>
```

Basically I loop through an object and assign labels and values to a `Picker.Item`. This is what the object looks like:

```
{
    "ProvinceID": 140100000,
    "Province": "Abra",
    "CountryID": 142,
    "RegionID": 0
},
{
    "ProvinceID": 160200000,
    "Province": "Agusan del Norte",
    "CountryID": 142,
    "RegionID": 0
},
```

Getting the value is find because `onValueChange` has a parameters that takes `itemValue`, but I want to get the `key` from the `Picker.Item` and put it as an argument on my `handleProvinceChange();` function.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the itemIndex and get the item in the array like below

```
 onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => {
    setProvince(itemValue);
    const ProvinceID = dProvinces[itemIndex].ProvinceID;
    handleProvinceChange();
  }}
```

Comment: It works, thank you very much. It would have been nice if there was an event sender variable in React Native like JS/ReactJS. I'll leave this open for now and hopefully get another answer as I mentioned.

Comment: I dont think thats available in this library though, thats why i have this option :)

Answer (score 0):

```
You can use item (index) and get the item in the array 


import React, { useState } from "react";
import { View, Picker, StyleSheet } from "react-native";

const App = () => {
  const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState("java");
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Picker
        selectedValue={selectedValue}
        style={{ height: 50, width: 150 }}
        onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) => setSelectedValue(itemValue)}
      >
        <Picker.Item label="Java" value="java" />
        <Picker.Item label="JavaScript" value="js" />
      </Picker>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 40,
    alignItems: "center"
  }
});

export default App;
```